# Como juntar duas linhas na mesma escala do gráfico?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Ola!

Eu tenho o código seguinte:

```
def createGraph():
    plt.title("Evolution of COVID-19")
    plt.xlabel("Days")
    plt.ylabel("Infected People")

    countries = ['China', 'Italy']
    days = [1,...,63] #Array from 1 to 63

    for country in countries:
        #createArray(country, type) returns an array with 63 values
        plt.plot(days, createArray('China', "infected"), color = 'red')

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

O gráfico que aparece é o seguinte:

[image: Gráfico resultante]

Como podem ver, o eixo dos Y quebra a meio e recomeça do 0... Alguém me sabe ajudar para colocar as duas linhas a começar do 0 (canto inferior esquerdo)?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O meu deu certo:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def createGraph():
    plt.title("Evolution of COVID-19")
    plt.xlabel("Days")
    plt.ylabel("Infected People")

    countries = ['China', 'Italy']
    days = [1, 2, 3] #Array from 1 to 63

    infect = {
        'China': [10, 20, 30],
        'Italy': [11, 80, 170]
            }

    for country in countries:
        #createArray(country, type) returns an array with 63 values
        plt.plot(days, infect[country])

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

createGraph()
```

Gostaria que você pudesse enviar o código todo para eu poder ver direito, eu tive que adaptar muitas coisas para funcionar. Do jeito que eu fiz não empilhou, ficou certinho.